# Add dependencies to files inside `project` directory

Tags: scala, sbt

So, I have smth like

```
...
settings {
  lazy val stress_test = taskKey[Unit]("simple stress test")
  stress_test := StressTest.main()
}
```

in my `build.sbt`. That class, `StressTest`, is located in `project` directory, and it will use some libraries like gatling or jmeter. But how can I add library dependencies to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `project` directory is itself an SBT project. So the dependencies go into either `project/*.sbt` or `project/project/*.scala`.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce code duplication, like declaring one scalaVersion twice?

Comment: Also, I cannot add dependency for, for example, Play's javaWs, even if I duplicated resolver in project/project/plugins.sbt.

Comment: Don't declare `scalaVersion` in the nested project at all: it has to use the version SBT itself is compiled with (2.10.5 for 0.13.9, IIRC).

Comment: Also, `project/project/plugins.sbt` would be used for building `project/project`, not `project`.

Comment: Yes, and here happens the "code duplication", because both `plugins.sbt` are identical. However, this is really minor issue, comparing to original one. Thank you very much :)